# Filter large number of records on mysql when using INNER JOIN with two fields

Tags: mysql, join, stored-procedures, inner-join

I'm working on existing database with millions of inserts per day. Database design itself pretty bad and filtering records from it takes huge amount of time. we are in the process of moving this to ELK cluster but in the mean time I have to filter some records for immediate use.

I have two tables like this

```
table - log_1

        datetime         |   id     |   name    |   ip

    2017-01-01 01:01:00  |  12345   |    sam    |     192.168.100.100


table - log_2

         datetime        |   mobile    |   id

    2017-01-01 01:01:00  |  999999999  |  12345
```

I need to filter my data using ip and from the log_1 and datetime on both log_1 and log_2. to do that I use below  query

```
SELECT log_1.datetime, log_1.id, log_1.name, log_1.ip, log_2,datetime, log_2.mobile, log_2.id
FROM log_1
INNER JOIN log_2
ON log_1.id = log_2.id AND log_1.datetime = log_2.datetime
where log_1.ip = '192.168.100.100'
limit 100
```

Needless to say this take forever to retrieve results with such large number of records. is there any better method  I can do the same thing without waiting long time mysql to respond ?. In other words how can I optimized my query against such large database.

database is not production and it's for just analytics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your current `LIMIT` clause is fairly meaningless, because the query has no `ORDER BY` clause.  It is not clear *which* 100 records you want to retain.  So, you might want to use something like this:

```
SELECT
    l1.datetime,
    l1.id,
    l1.name,
    l1.ip,
    l2.datetime,
    l2.mobile,
    l2.id
FROM log_1 l1
INNER JOIN log_2 l2
    ON l1.id = l2.id AND l1.datetime = l2.datetime
WHERE
    l1.ip = '192.168.100.100'
ORDER BY
    l1.datetime DESC
LIMIT 100;
```

This would return the 100 most recent matching records.  As for speeding up this query, one way to at least make the join faster would be to add the following index on the `log_2` table:

```
CREATE INDEX idx ON log_2 (datetime, id, mobile);
```

Assuming MySQL chooses to use this index, it should make the join much faster, because each `id` and `datetime` value can be looked up in a B-tree instead of doing a manual scan of the entire table.  Note that the index also covers the `mobile` column, which is needed in the select.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I add limit 100 only for testing my query in workbench. in real world I need to retrieve all the records which is around 2000-2500 per given second

Comment: @gripenfighter My answer doesn't really change based on that.

Comment: I managed to solve my issue by adding proper indexing to the table as well as moving portion of the data to a temporary table as other answer suggested. Thanks for the answer

Comment: Glad I could help.  Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this :
1. Create index on both tables on id column if not already created (this will take time).

2. Try creating two temp tables log_1_tmp and log_2_tmp with data as below :

```
Query 1 - insert into log_1_tmp select * from log_1 where log_1.ip = '192.168.100.100'

Query 2 - insert into log_2_tmp select * from log_2 where log_2.ip = '192.168.100.100'
```

3. Run your query on above two tables and here you can remove where condition from your query.

See if this works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this method also